# Can leaflet notify me when a certain area is in the view?

Tags: leaflet, geofencing

I have several GeoJSON features on the map and wonder if `leaflet` could notify me when I am over a feature. I think that's geofencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and there is nothing very complicated to implement it.

What do you mean by "I am over a feature"?

If you mean your mouse pointer or a kind of marker / point that represents your current position, you would simply need a plugin like [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) to determine which features contain your position, if any (react on map[`"mousemove"` event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-mousemove) for the mouse).

If you mean the current map view intersects some of the features, that would be slightly more complex, but still easily solved through another library like [turf](http://turfjs.org/). Look for [`turf.intersect` method](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_intersect.html). You would need to iterate over all your features, checked against a rectangle built from the current map view (probably something like: `L.rectangle(map.getBounds()).toGeoJSON()`).

Comment: `turf` looks like what I need. Thanks!